# How can we force a puppet manifest and module syntax check prior to version control check-in?

Tags: svn, puppet, configuration-management, version-control

I am working on deploying version control for our `puppet` modules and manifests.

I want to enforce a workflow that requires a puppet module and manifest code check prior to a check-in of changes. This would be useful since it would prevent the pushing of code changes with, for e.g., syntax errors or something more fatal.

My initial thoughts were to deploy a whole separate `puppetmaster` instance where manifests and module changes can be done and have it be a node of itself. A syntax check could then be done with a `service puppetmaster restart && service puppet restart` and checking the logs for errors. I could code that workflow in a manifest and module push script. However, I'm thinking there's a more elegant way.

Comment: Pre-/Post-commit hooks? Like these: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/puppet_version_control ?

Comment: Thanks. Google'd around but did not find that. Checking it out now. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you'd configure a pre- or post-commit hook in your favorite revision control system.
There are some example scripts at: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/puppet_version_control